# MDT 2013 Update 2 Sysprep and Capture doesnt even show up

Tags: windows-7, deployment, mdt

TL;DR: Fresh MDT server Build, Image deployments (windows 7) work great.  Image capturing (windows 7) does not function at all.

**Environment:**

- Windows Server 2016
- WDS Role installed
- MDT 6.3.8443 (2013 update 2)

**Status:**

- Current *deployments* work fine
- One deployment share
- One capture share
- litetouch.vbs starts up and allows me to select task sequence

**Steps**

- Capture task sequence created properly
- Custom settings:

> [Settings]
> Priority=Default
>
> Properties=MyCustomProperty
>
> [Default]
>
> SkipCapture=NO
>
> DoCapture=YES
>
> OSInstall=Y
>
> SkipAdminPassword=YES
>
> SkipProductKey=YES
>
> SkipComputerBackup=YES
>
> SkipBitLocker=YES

- Bootstrap.ini file:

> [Settings]
>
> Priority=Default
>
> [Default]
>
> DeployRoot=\ipaddressofserver\Deployment$

**Problem**

When running the litetouch vbs file, it pulls up, and allows me to select the task sequence that I want.  Usually this pulls up, and when I select the "capture" task sequence I built, it has an option on the side to "Capture Image" like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmNWh.png)

But as of right now, that "capture image" option does not show up, even with the bootstrap and customsettings setup as outlined above.

I have burned my MDT server to the ground, and started fresh.  Same deal.  I've recreated shares, task sequences, same deal.

Anyone have any insights?  Deployments again, work just fine, but capturing does not work at all right now.

Answer (score 1):

Had same problem. Found this:
ZTIUtility.vbs

```
If (oTS.SelectSingleNode("//step[@type='BDD_InstallOS']") is nothing) and (oTS.SelectSingleNode("//step[@type='BDD_UpgradeOS']") is nothing) then
```

And change it to:

```
If (oTS.SelectSingleNode("//step[@type='BDD_InstallOS' and @disable='false']") is nothing) and (oTS.SelectSingleNode("//step[@type='BDD_UpgradeOS' and @disable='false']") is nothing) then
```

Comment: Rebuilt my entire mdt server.  Will be testing this function today.

Comment: Changing that line worked for me to get the capture screen to show up. However, the Sys Prep on Windows 10 failed, and so I'm working through that right now.